# hive ngram stopword list?

Tags: hadoop, hive, n-gram

While listed as one of the [example use cases](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/statisticsanddatamining.html) ... I haven't found an example of filtering out junk words (and, or, etc) from a Hive n-gram.

```
SELECT explode(context_ngrams(sentences(lower(description)), array("criminal", null), 10)) AS x FROM mapped_discussions;

{"ngram":["justice"],"estfrequency":274.0}
{"ngram":["behavior"],"estfrequency":121.0}
{"ngram":["law"],"estfrequency":92.0}
{"ngram":["activity"],"estfrequency":69.0}
{"ngram":["acts"],"estfrequency":41.0}
{"ngram":["procedure"],"estfrequency":35.0}
{"ngram":["and"],"estfrequency":29.0}
{"ngram":["or"],"estfrequency":27.0}
{"ngram":["case"],"estfrequency":26.0}
{"ngram":["cases"],"estfrequency":25.0}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent post on this topic here. http://bigdatabloggin.blogspot.com/2012/08/trending-topics-in-hive-ngrams.html